# Updating data in mysql db from bash script

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, insert

It's my first time trying to insert some info in a mysql database with an executable .sh file.

I'm using the following bash script but it's not working. Obviously most of the vars below have been replaced and simplified for ease of understanding.

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql -D mydbname -u mydbuser -p mydbpass <<EOF
INSERT INTO mytable (mycolumn) VALUES ('myvalue') WHERE id = '13';

exit;
```

You can see that I only want to insert my value in the row where id = 13 and this row does exist.

I don't think i'm formatting the query properly am I?

EDIT : Ok after suggestions below i've now got this but it still doesn't work?

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -D mydbname -u mydbuser -p mydbpass <<EOF
UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn = 'myvalue' WHERE id = '13';
exit;
```

Comment: You mix insert and update syntax. That do not work.

Comment: The query itself is wrong. `INSERT` doesn't have `WHERE` clause

Comment: Doh! Of course you are right.. Major oversight on my part.. Feel very silly now :(

Answer (score 16):

Found the answer after some trial and error.

Just in case anybody else is looking to do the same thing it's :

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql -u username -puserpass dbname -e "UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn = 'myvalue' WHERE id='myid'";
```

Note that there is no space between the -p and your password **-puserpass** if you put a space there **-p userpass** it will prompt you for the password.

Hope it helps somebody ;)

Comment: The heredoc method will work as well if it uses proper SQL and bash syntax. But both that approach and the one above are rather inefficient when you want to execute multiple statements - and it won't work for transactions. In such scenarios, piping the output of a bash script to mysql's stdin will be more efficient and support transactions.

Comment: @symcbean, re: *"piping the output of a bash script to mysql's stdin will be more efficient and support transactions"*. Perhaps you should provide an example.

Answer (score 4):

The solution works like a charm as specified in the above post. You could also use the -D option while specifying the dbname.

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql -u username -puserpass -D dbname -e "UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn = 'myvalue' WHERE id='myid'";
```

For additional reference on the options, refer below link: https://www.shellhacks.com/mysql-run-query-bash-script-linux-command-line/

Answer (score 3):

Your query doesn't work as you have not typed EOF at the end of the script. See my example below.

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql -u root -ppassword DB_NAME <<EOF
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE NAME='YOURNAME';
SELECT * FROM ANOTHER_TABLE WHERE SOMETHING_ELSE;
... more queries
EOF
```

Note that the -ppassword argument can be skipped if the connection does not require a password.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me as well:   **escape the quote like so \"**

```
mysql -u userName --password=yourPassword -D databaseName -e "UPDATE tableName SET columnName = \"${variable}\" WHERE numberColumn = \"${numberVariable}\""
```